# Looping 2 set of results twice

Tags: php, loops

I have a page where I need to pull the titles of 3 of the latest records in one bootstrap row and then few lines further in the next row I need to pull the image of each record (only 3) again.

How can I do this?

[image: Picture Showing How i need to pull data]

Comment: Please, add code as code, and not as image. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the image stored as a link in db?

Comment: Harshit, Images stored as file name only.

Answer (score 0):

On your loop construct two series of HTML entries, one for your titles and another one for your pictrures. Then echo each HTML string to the div you want them to be.

```
<?php
titlesHTML = "";
imagesHTML = "";

foreach ($result as $row) {
   $contentTitle = $row['cont_title'];
   $contentImage = $row['cont_picture'];
   $titlesHTML .= "<p>" . $contentTitle . "</p>";
   $imagesHTML .= "<p>" . $contentImage . "</p>";
   // if you want not to echo the image location but the image itself try the following code instead:
   // $imagesHTML .= "<img src='" . $contentImage . "'>";
}
?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-em-12">
    <?php echo $titlesHTML; ?>
  </div>
<div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-em-12">
    <?php echo $imagesHTML; ?>
  </div>
<div>
```